# Uneditable column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, power-automate, flow

I have a column in the SharePoint list in which the name of the person who edited the previous column appears (using a power automate), I need this column to be no longer editable after the name appears.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to make this field non-editable from SharePoint "out of the box list forms" or non-editable from everywhere (from Power automate or Power apps or API calls)?

Comment: I want the column to be editable for power automate only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements, you have to hide the list column/field from SharePoint default list forms.

1. Open the "New" list item form
2. Choose "Edit columns" option as shown:

   [image]
3. In the Edit columns pane, uncheck (to hide) the checkbox for the column needed.
4. When you're finished, select Save.

**Documentation**: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

---

**Note**: Users might be able to edit the column value using **Edit in grid view** option. To avoid this, you can disable this option from:

1. List settings > Advanced settings
2. Set "Allow items in this list to be edited using Quick Edit and the Details Pane?" to "No
3. Click "OK"